# Silverlight - Grabbing all binding information of elements in a given visual stree?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, xaml

We are loading some xaml for an Element at runtime (XamlReader.Load) for some preview purposes. Need less to say, the properties/bindings are not know as they can vary across elements/controls we are loading.

As the run time view model context is not available when we load the control for preview - after loading the Element, the idea is to grab the binding information, create a type with those propertes at run time, to assign the same as the data context of the loaded control.

We'll be using AssemblyBuilder/ModuleBuilder/TypeBuilder to build a type at run time. Having said that, we need to walk the visual tree to identify the bindings involved, to create a list of binding paths.

Obviously, one way is to use regex to parse the xaml directly and build this list.. Just want to know a way exist so that I can grab the bindings and related paths from the visual tree itself?

Thanks

Comment: I often see the wpf tag  included in a silverlight question, is there really a wpf component to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just walk the Silverlight Visual Tree and for each element call GetBindingExpression() for all of it's DPs?

Comment: One dev's "simple" is another dev's "yikes!".

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily the enumerate the bindings themselves from the visual tree.  The primary showstopper is that the `FrameworkElement` does not provide a means to enumerate bindings that have been applied using the `SetBinding` method.

In order to discover the bindings set on a FrameworkElement you would need to discover the set of possible DependencyProperties that may or may not have been set then attempt to retrieve each with `GetBindingExpression`.  To discover the set of DependencyProperties would require some reflection code over the actual type of the FrameworkElement.

A more likely alternative would be to load the XAML into an XDocument, you could then use some LINQ to discover all Attributes that start with `"{Binding"`.  But yes it would then be a case of RegEx to parse the attribute value (unless you want to do something really mad that I won't even mention).